# Trying to get the max/min in array

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, max, min

Im trying to get the min value in a column in the row of the max value. Im trying to using for loops but its not working.

Let say a matrix A:

3 4 5
2 3 4
1 2 3

I want the program to find the max value in the [0]th row then find the min value in the colunm of the max.
So result should be : max of row [0] = 5, min of column [2] = 3.
I then want it to do the same of all the rows, that why I ysed a while loop.

Here is the matrix:

```
public int[][] createMatrix(int a, int b){
    Scanner  inputm = new Scanner(System.in);
  A = new int[a][b];  
System.out.println("Enter elements for matrix A : ");
for (int i=0 ; i < A.length ; i++){
    System.out.println("Enter numbers for " + i +"th row");
for  (int j=0 ; j < A[i].length ; j++){
A[i][j] = inputm.nextInt();

    }

}
return A;
}

public int[][] displayMatrix(){
 System.out.println("Matrix A: ");

    for (int i=0 ; i < A.length ; i++)
    {     System.out.println();
        for  (int j=0 ; j < A[i].length ; j++){
            System.out.print(A[i][j]+" ");
              }
    }


return A;

}


public int getMaximumOfEveryRow (int c){ 
    a=c;
int i= 0;
int j;
 while(i < A[a].length){

    max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (  j = 0; j < A [ i ].length; j++ )
        if ( A [ i ] [ j ] > max ){
            max = A [ i ] [ j ];
        }



            for (  i = 0; i < A [ i ].length; i++ )// e
        if ( A [ i ] [ j ] < min ){
            min = A [ i ] [ j ];
        }

        System.out.println( "\n Maximum of row " + j + " = " + max );
    System.out.println( "Minimum of column " + i + " = " + min );        
    if(max == min){
    System.out.println( min+ " = " + max );
    System.out.println( "This is a saddle point. ");
    }




    i++;

 }     
return max;


}
```

and this is what I have so far:

```
public int getMaximumOfEveryRow (int c){ 
    a=c;
int i= 0;
int j;
 while(i < A[a].length){

    max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (  j = 0; j < A [ i ].length; j++ )
        if ( A [ i ] [ j ] > max ){
            max = A [ i ] [ j ];
        }


    int e = j;  
    int r;
            for (  i = 0; i < A [ i ].length; i++ )// e
        if ( A [ i ] [ j ] < min ){
            min = A [ i ] [ j ];
        }

        System.out.println( "\n Maximum of row " + j + " = " + max );
    System.out.println( "Minimum of column " + i + " = " + min );        
    if(max == min){
    System.out.println( min+ " = " + max );
    System.out.println( "This is a saddle point. ");
    }




    i++;

 }     
return max;


}
public int getMaximumOfEveryColumn ()
{
for ( int i = 0; i < A.length; i++ )
{
    maxc = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for ( int j = 0; j < A [ i ].length; j++ )
        if ( A [ j ] [ i ] > maxc )
            maxc = A [ j ] [ i ];
    System.out.println( "Maximum of column " + i + " = " + maxc );
}
return maxc;
}

public int getMinimumOfEveryColumn_(){
for ( int i = 0; i < A.length; i++ )
{
    minc = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for ( int j = 0; j < A [ i ].length; j++ )
        if ( A [ j ] [ i ] < minc )
            minc = A [ j ] [ i ];
    System.out.println( "Minimum of column " + i + " = " + minc );
}
return minc;
}
public int getMaximumOfEveryRow ()
{
for ( int i = 0; i < A.length; i++ )
{
    maxr = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for ( int j = 0; j < A [ i ].length; j++ )
        if ( A [ i ] [ j ] > maxr )
            maxr = A [ i ] [ j ];
    System.out.println( "Maximum of row " + i + " = " + maxr );
}
return maxr;
}
```

code for finding the max value in colunm and then finding the min value in the row of that max value.

```
public void get_max_of_the_row_of_local_min ()
{
 for ( int i = 0; i < A.length; i++ )
 {
    min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int index_of_min_in_its_col = 0;



    //maxc = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for ( int j = 0; j < A [ i ].length; j++ )

        if ( A [ j ] [ i ] > max ){
            max = A [ j ] [ i ];
            index_of_min_in_its_col = i;
            System.out.println( " Maximum of col [" + i + "] = " + max);
        }

   for ( int j = 0; j < A [ index_of_min_in_its_col ].length; j++ )

        if ( A [ index_of_min_in_its_col ] [ index_of_min_in_its_col ] < min ){
            min = A [ index_of_min_in_its_col ] [ index_of_min_in_its_col ];
   a =j;
        }
    //System.out.print( " Maximum of col [" + j + "] = " + max);
    System.out.println( " Minimum of rol [" + index_of_min_in_its_col + "] = " + min );

    if(max == min){
    System.out.println("This is a saddle point.");
    }

 }
```

Comment: Can you show how the matrix is defined? It is listed all in one line, so it's unclear where the second row starts.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen I just edited it.

Comment: What is A[a] ? Where does a come from?

Comment: @ayokunleadeosun improve the code formatting. If your are using eclipse - CTRL+SHIFT+F

Comment: @gt_ebuddy Sorry I use Netbeans.

Comment: @ayokunleadeosun check my solution by reading the explanation as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
public void get_minimum_of_the_column_of_local_maximum ()
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < A.length; i++ )
    {
        min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int index_of_maximum_in_its_row = 0;

        for ( int j = 0; j < A [ i ].length; j++ )
            if ( A [ i ] [ j ] > max )
                {
                    max = A [ i ] [ j ];
                    index_of_maximum_in_its_row = j;
                }

        for ( int j = 0; j < A [ index_of_maximum_in_its_row ].length; j++ )
            if ( A [ j ] [ index_of_maximum_in_its_row ] < min )
                min = A [ j ] [ index_of_maximum_in_its_row ];

        System.out.print( " Maximum of row [" + i + "] = " + max);
        System.out.println( " Minimum of column [" + index_of_maximum_in_its_row + "] = " + min );
    }
}
```

What does this code snippet do?

You have `min = Integer.MAX_VALUE, max = Integer.MIN_VALUE` variables. The reason we assign these values to this numbers is to make finding max/min possible. How? Initially `min` has the greatest integer value but as far as we find a value less than it we update our minimum so the `min`'s value decreases. Same technique with `max` variable but of course it goes the other direction by increasing in value after comparisons.

First inner for loop determines the maximum of row *i*, then marks the index of maximum in that row by using variable `index_of_maximum_in_its_row`. It is required to be used later on in the second inner loop.

Second inner loop determines the minimum of column number `index_of_maximum_in_its_row` with one iteration over that column. Than the method prints the results.

Comment: Thanks I'm also trying to use this to find the mac value in a column and then find the min value in the row of the row. I would paste it here if I could But I'll edit my original.

Comment: @ayokunleadeosun if you read my post i think it is self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest implementation.

```
for(int i=0; i<arr.length ; i++){
    int columnNumber = getMaxElementsColumnNumber(arr,i); // i will represent row number
    int minElement = getMinimumElementInColumn(arr,columnNumber);
}
```

getMaxElementsColumnNumber() will print the maximum number in current row and will return the column number of that element

getMinimumElementInColumn() will traverse column of matrix and return the minimum element in that column.

You can implement code in the same for loop. In this way you can also check for the saddle point.

Comment: Is getMaxElementsColumnNumber() and getMinimumElementInColumn() static?

Comment: It depends upon the method in which this for loop will be written. If that method is static the you also need to make these two methods static.  This is just a sample code demonstrating the logic that can be used to solve your problem. You can implement as these methods in whatever way that is comfortable for you as long as they solve the problem.